# How to boot from USB/CD without the BIOS password

Tags: windows, ntfs

I need to be able to view/delete copy to files to a NTFS hard drive.

At first, I used a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), but when I went to my target computer, there was a BIOS password on it. Is there a way or program to view, copy and or delete files from the NTFS hard drive without being booted to the Windows operating system?

Also, all files will be reset after reboot due to a program called [Deep Freeze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29), which restores it to the preset configuration.

Comment: I don't see any possibility short of a back door bios password in this situation, especially when removing the hard drive is not a option.

Comment: What would be the point of a bios password if it could be easily bypassed. Reset or remove the bios password, depending on the system how this is accomplished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Remove the drive and hook it up to another machine
2. Clear the [nonvolatile BIOS memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory) (CMOS) (usually a jumper) or if that doesn't work, pull the battery and short the positive to the negative (force power drain). These methods usually clear a password out.

Comment: Sadly, I would not be in a position to take the computer apart.

Comment: @P'sao,impossible without out taking the computer apart. Sorry.